# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\\ --access-logfile'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, gunicorn

please i need help with gunicorn. i am a junior developer in python. i was setting up a server for a client, when i came across this error No module named '\ --access-logfile'.

this is the gunicorn.service unit

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
```

this is the gunicorn.service Service

```
[Service]
User=metalcode
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/metalcode
ExecStart=/home/metalcode/env/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        gworldtc.wsgi:application
```

please help me.

Comment: `run gunicorn --config config.py app:app --access-logfile '-'`   And see if anything is logged on stdout(console output)?

Comment: Gunicorn configuration is very sensitive. Be sure you don't have any space in between. 
In your case is trying to find module named `\ --access-logfile`, so I guess something isn't well written. Sometimes rewriting helps.